# VB.net - Agregar un array a otro

Tags: array, vb.net

Mi consulta es la siguiente: Estoy con VB.net y tengo dos arrays cargados. Lo que necesito hacer es agregar un array a otro. Es decir:

dim array1() as integer

dim array2() as integer

'se cargan los dos arrays...

Quiero tener en array1 lo que tenía antes más los elementos del array2. Cómo hago? Hice un par de pruebas pero me voy de índice.

Nota: Los arreglos pueden tener entre 20 y 30 elementos aproximadamente.

Ahí va lo que probé:

```
 dim array1() as object1 
 dim array2() as object1 
 dim tamanio as integer = array1.lenght 
 dim a as integer = tamanio 

 For Each ev As object1 In array1 
    array1(a) = ev 
    a = a + 1 
 Next
```

El problema lo tira en donde hago a = a + 1 porque ese índice no existe, claro. Leí por ahí que por ahí lo que tengo que hacer es un Redim adentro del For Each para cada elemento nuevo pero me parece poco eficiente. Tiene que haber otra manera

Comment: que probaste? asi podemos corregir lo que haces mal...

Comment: Perdón, no sé por que queda todo el texto junto y no respeta los "enter"

Comment: Porque eso que escribiste es un comentario, y es solo para aclaraciones. Deberias modificar tu pregunta usando el boton [edit] y agregar el codigo ahi... De paso, mira el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la pagina y tambien mira [ask]

Comment: Ahí edité la pregunta.

Comment: porque redim te parece poco eficiente? esa es una forma de hacerlo.. tambien podrias hacer un solo redim al tamaño final y agregar los indices.. tambien podes crear un nuevo array del tamaño final y copiar los dos array ahi, y luego sobreescribir el primer array... pero si vas a agregar cosas a un array que tiene un tamaño definido, si tenes que usar redim... o usar una lista que tiene tamaño variable...

Comment: Muy bien. Esa era la duda... Pensé en hacerlo con una lista que es mejor para este caso pero estoy tocando un proyecto ya hecho y no quiero cambiar lo que ya anda. jaja

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
 Dim array1() as object1 
 Dim array2() as object1 
 Dim array3() as object1 

 Dim tam_1 As Integer = array1.Length
 Dim tam_2 As Integer

 array3 = array1 

 'se cargan array1 y array2

 tam_2 = array2.Length
 ReDim array1(tam_1 + tam_2 - 1)

 array3.CopyTo(array1, 0)
 array2.CopyTo(array1, tam_1)
```

Finalmente, en array1, tengo los datos que tenía antes mas los del array2.

Muchas gracias.